# Is there a way to quickly identify malformed xml components in a file using Visual Studio?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010

I have several large XML files that have been corrupted in strange ways... certain characters have been added/ removed at seemingly random intervals.

When I paste the text into an XML file in Visual Studio, the IDE will identify problems with the file (illegal chars, missing spaces etc) by underlining it.  The problem is, these files are pretty big and I don't want to try scrolling through them, looking for the red squiggly lines.

Is there a way (like some shortcut key/ sequence) to jump from one problem area to the next?  The data in these files is already suspect, but if I can at least load them into my importer the other problems will be easier to fix.

Comment: Did you look at the [Error List Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a.aspx) while the file is open? Double clicking an error line should take you to that line.

Comment: Ah excellent, I did not realize it would appear in there.  Is there a key combination to go to the next error then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Oded stated, one can quickly navigate to the XML errors by double-clicking them in the error list window.  I was unable to find a key shortcut, but it was not super necessary.  This sufficed.